# Close a Vuetify v-dialog in a custom component when using v-slot:activator

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am trying to create a custom component that wraps a Vuetify v-dialog.

I am having trouble with closing the dialog using a button inside the dialog.

I've tried many things, like `@emit('input', false)`, `this.value = false` or using a local data value instead of `value`, but nothing seems to work.

My dialog looks like this (simplified):

```html
// file: DeleteDialog.vue
<template>
  <v-dialog :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event)" width="550">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <slot
          name="activator"
          v-bind:on="on"
          v-bind:attrs="attrs"></slot>
    </template>

    <v-btn @click="closeDialog">
      Close
    </v-btn>

  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: Boolean,
  },
  methods: {
    closeDialog() {
      this.$emit('input', false);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

When using the dialog like this, how do I get the Close-button to work?

```html
<DeleteDialog>
  <template v-slot:activator="{on, attrs">
    <v-btn v-on="on" v-bind="attrs">
      Show dialog
    </v-btn>
  </template>
  Are you sure you want to delete this user?
</DeleteDialog>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prop you pass `value` is responsible for showing or hiding your `v-dialog` inside `DeleteDialog.vue`.
So when clicking the button close, we will emit an event `close` that will maake the parent of `DeleteDialog` change the prop `value` it passed to it as false.

```
// in your parent component
<DeleteDialog :value="show_dialog" @close="show_dialog = false>
```

in your deleteDialog

```
//in delete dialog
<template>
  <v-dialog :value="value" width="550">

    <v-btn @click="closeDialog">
      Close
    </v-btn>

  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: Boolean,
  },
  methods: {
    closeDialog() {
      this.$emit('close');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I think that is more suitable way of achieving what you want

Comment: Thenk you. Your solution might work, but I'd like to use the `v-slot:activator` syntax and I can't figure out how to combine that with your solution.

Comment: please, try the `closeDialog` I wrote and  `<DeleteDialog :value="show_dialog" @close="show_dialog = false> ..... </DeleteDialog>`

Comment: I must have made a spelling error or something that was causing my problem. I was finaly able to get this working the way you suggested. A working version can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-vuetify-dialog-using-activator-slot-0i3re?file=/src/components/DeleteDialog.vue